# Use of local variable 'BtnPressed' before its declaration

Tags: swift

Cant figured out what wrong with my code

> "self.toggleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnPressed), for:
>   .touchUpInside)" - Use of local variable 'BtnPressed' before its
>   declaration

Changing the name of the function

```
//Flashlight Bottom
self.toggleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        var switchStatus: SwitchStatus = .off

        func BtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            switchStatus.toggle()
            if switchStatus == .off {
                toggleOff()
                view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1468022913, green: 0.1468022913, blue: 0.1468022913, alpha: 1)
                toggleBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "offBtn"), for: .normal)
                onOffLbl.text = "OFF"
                onOffLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
            } else {
                toggleOn()
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                toggleBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "onBtn"), for: .normal)
                onOffLbl.text = "ON"
                onOffLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a quick demo on playground showing how it should be declared, the main issue there is that you are trying to add the target outside a method and before you declare the selector.

```
var switchStatus: SwitchStatus = .off
var onOffLbl = UILabel()
var toggleBtn = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)

func toggleOn() {
    // ...
}

func toggleOff() {
    // ...
}

@objc func BtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switchStatus.toggle()
    if switchStatus == .off {
        toggleOff()
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1468022913, green: 0.1468022913, blue: 0.1468022913, alpha: 1)
        toggleBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "offBtn"), for: .normal)
        onOffLbl.text = "OFF"
        onOffLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        toggleOn()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        toggleBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "onBtn"), for: .normal)
        onOffLbl.text = "ON"
        onOffLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

func setupActions() {
    toggleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```